# Email does not save in quote_address table until after order is placed

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.4

Email does not save in quote_address table until after order is placed.
How can I save email in quote_address table along with all other address information in quote_address table at the same time as the other address information (ie: right after customer clicks on the Next button, after they have filled in their address details)?